# Vim regex substitution pattern not found

Tags: regex, vim

I have a regex substitution I would like to perform on Vim and the command I have is as follows:

```
:%s/\s\s(\w)(.*):\s(.*,)/const get\U$1\L$2 = state => $3/g
```

Problem is, it says the pattern is not found.

Here I have it working on regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/dOmgJy/1

Comment: You have it working with PCRE syntax.  Vim has its own syntax for regexps, which is substantially different from PCRE (cf. `:h regexp`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct regex for vim will be

```
:%s/\s\s\(\w\)\(.*\):\s\(.*,\)/const get\U$1\L$2 = state => $3/g
```

you need to escape the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I figured it out. I have to escape all the parentheses and for capture groups, replacement isn't with dollar signs but with backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Vim regexp has a concept it calls "magic". You can start your regexp with specific sequence and it changes how that regexp is interpreted.

Most people will find the "very magic" setting (`\v`) the most familiar when coming from PCRE:

`:%s/\v\s\s(\w)(.*):\s(.*,)/const get\U\1\L\2 = state => \3/g`

Aside from correcting the capture references (`$1` -> `\1`) the only other change from your original was to prepend the `\v` sequence to pattern.

[Vim's official docs on regexp magic](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic)